# PhoneGap for Games, yes or no?

Tags: android, cordova

So I am considering developing some android apps, however, I am a web developer, and as such I am considering using PhoneGap. Would it be a bad idea to develop a game using PhoneGap? Would it be better for me to learn JAVA?

Are there any programs that allow for html5/javascript based app development and will be okay for games?

Regards

Matt

Comment: what kind of game? Flappy2048? Or 3D car racing game?

Comment: Probably a low-rez game with lots of gif spirtes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I will tell you that PhoneGap Dont give the users the real feeling of android app
and this is hart the download rate.

also java is very easy to learn but android game developing its very hard to begginers you need to love it

**So this is your choose have fun**

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: *it depends on the game*.

As far as how a non-native app's user interface "feels", games enjoy a special privilege: they often have their own look and feel that doesn't relate to the platform on which they run. This means that it really doesn't matter if the game feels "native" or not, because quite a few games use their own user interface anyway. (Now, if the game is trying to appear "native", then you may have a problem. But aim for a unique user interface within the game, and I doubt a user could tell the difference.)

What's most important is that your game is *smooth*. To do that, you need to target 60 frames per second, and that's not always easy to do, especially if you are drawing a lot of content or calculating a lot of interactions. Simple games will probably do just fine, but more complex games (say, a 3D racing game) would have problems meeting 60 fps.

There's one other fly in the ointment: Android 4.4 does *not* hardware-accelerate the canvas, which means that no matter how hard you try, you can't get much better than a few frames per second (on a canvas that fills the screen). Which is unfortunate, because 4.3 (though it had its own quirks) could reach 60fps without a problem (assuming a sufficiently powerful device).

Most of the libraries that support game development are the same that support game development for the web. If it works online, you can probably use it in PhoneGap -- just pay attention to the fact that your device is several orders of magnitude slower than your desktop and its web browser. So don't assume that because your game runs smoothly on your desktop browser that it will do so on a device.

All that said, if you want the absolute best performance, you're going to have to go native. *But* for simpler games, it isn't always a *necessary*. It just depends on the type of the game.

**Note:** If your game is something more like, say, a quiz game, then hitting frame rates and using the canvas are probably non issues for you. If it's that style of game, Phonegap can definitely work, and work well.